# Getting most_common tags with django-taggit, ignoring certain tagged objects

Tags: django, django-taggit

I'm using django-taggit to tag some objects, Bookmarks. The Bookmarks have a boolean `is_private` attribute.

When fetching a list of the most frequently-used tags I can do this:

```
Bookmark.tags.most_common()
```

But how would I get the most frequently-used tags ignoring all the tags on `is_private` Bookmarks? If it helps, there's a `Bookmark.public_objects` manager which only returns the non-private Bookmarks.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across the answer while looking through the django-taggit docs and code for something else. You can set a custom Manager on your model's `tags` attribute, and use this to add extra functionality.

So, previously, my Bookmark model had this:

```
from django.db import models
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Bookmark(models.Model):
    # Other attributes here
    tags = TaggableManager
```

I've now changed that to this:

```
from django.db import models
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager
from .managers import _BookmarkTaggableManager

class Bookmark(models.Model):
    # Other attributes here
    tags = TaggableManager(manager=_BookmarkTaggableManager)
```

And then in `myapp/managers.py` I have this:

```
from django.db import models
from taggit.managers import _TaggableManager

class _BookmarkTaggableManager(_TaggableManager):

    def most_common_public(self):
        extra_filters = {'bookmark__is_private': False}

        return self.get_queryset(extra_filters).annotate(
            num_times=models.Count(self.through.tag_relname())
        ).order_by('-num_times')
```

That `most_common_public()` method is a copy of django-taggit's standard [`most_common()` method](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit/blob/70eff0ee41a5e839e03e7b8caf17ad07799b5229/taggit/managers.py#L214) but with the addition of passing that `extra_filters` to the queryset.

Then when I want the list of most common tags, but excluding private Bookmarks, I use this:

```
Bookmark.tags.most_common_public()
```

There might be a different method -- I'm a little uneasy about duplicating the entire query from `most_common()` for instance -- but this seems to work.

Comment: You could also completely override the default `most_common()` method, if you're never going to need that - rename `most_common_public` to `most_common`.